# How to replicate with code iOS Reminder Application graphic background

Tags: ios, objective-c

In order to reduce file size, I am trying to clean my app of all the unnecessary png graphics, by substituting, whenever possible, with code. The classic example is the UIView shadow which can be achieved by acting on the CALayer properties.

However I have a UITableViewCell with a background similiar to the reminders application in iPhone.

Such background can be achieved easily with photoshop with several techniques, by dropping an inner glow effect or by means of layer filters.

Is there a way I can replicate this with code only ? Here is a screenshot, I am not talking about the leather effect, but the reminders list background.

[image: Reminder Application]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do here is add noise to the view. The easiest way I know of doing that is with David Keegan's [KGNoise](https://github.com/kgn/KGNoise) project.

Comment: Yes, infact one of the techniques is to add a noise. I will give a try and let you know.

Comment: I just tried, it works perfectly, and it is just what I needed.